# Swagger permanent authorization token

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, swagger

I am developing web api in ASP.NET Core MVC. I wonder if there is a way to make authorization token in swagger persistent, so that the authorization does not need to be done manually every time the application is run. 
It would make testing easier.

Comment: Check my answer on a similar question 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69254262/11301126

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The local storage can be used for keeping the authorization token.

To store the token into the local storage, type into the browser console:

```
localStorage.setItem('authKey', 'the authorization token')
```

Then, use request interceptor to supply the token from the local storage as Authorization header:

```
const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
    url: "/swagger/v2/swagger.json",
    dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
    deepLinking: true,
    requestInterceptor: function (req) {
        var key = localStorage.getItem("authKey");

        if (key && key.trim() !== "") {
            req.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + key;
            console.log('Authorized from authKey');
        }
    },
    presets: [
        SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
        SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
    ],
    plugins: [
        SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl
    ],
    layout: "StandaloneLayout",
})

window.ui = ui;
```

Comment: receiving error, Uncaught referenceerror,  swaggerui bundle is not defined

Comment: also doing localStorage.setItem('key', ettc is giving undefined warning reply

Comment: Related - https://github.com/scottie1984/swagger-ui-express/issues/44#issuecomment-605088470

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `persistAuthorization` configuration parameter, which defaults to `false`.

In .Net, set the `app.UseSwaggerUI` `EnablePersistAuthorization` option:

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "v1");
    c.EnablePersistAuthorization();
});
```

In the official Docker image, this can be set using `PERSIST_AUTHORIZATION`.

See the [Swagger UI Configuration Docs](https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/usage/configuration/) and the [Pull Request](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/pull/2213).

Answer (score 1):

If you use .NET CORE **Swashbuckle**, you could do the following steps to persist authorization data.

1. Create an index.html for customizing SWAGGER UI configuration. An index.html should base on [the default version](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI/index.html)

2. Open index.html file you just created above, adding one line
   `configObject.persistAuthorization = true;` to persistAuthorization
   in window.onload event

Comment: This answer applies to any Swagger UI, not just Swashbuckle. If you are using .NET Core and Swashbuckle you can configure directly in the UseSwaggerUI options, see the answer by @vanenshi